# SurfaceView drawBitmap take too long, the longest time consuming 200ms

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, surfaceholder, drawbitmap

I am using Surface to show bitmap from JNI, to show a video, this is my code :

```
       SurfaceHolder holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
       while(true) {
            if(getBitmap() == null) {
                continue;
            }
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(getBitmap(), matrix, null);
            if(viewInterface == null) {
                break;
            }
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            setBitmap(null);
        }
```

I went to calculate the time spent in each method，I found that the method

```
//longest time consuming 71ms
holder.lockCanvas(); 

//longest time consuming 50ms
canvas.drawBitmap(getBitmap(), matrix, null);

//longest time consuming 111ms
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

I don't know where the problem is, what happens next time to drawBitmap for so long time

Comment: Include the `Matrix` in your code too. Any code in getBitmap()?

Comment: I use to canvas.drawBitmap(getBitmap(), 0, 0 , null); 
it also take a lot of time in lockCanvas(),
the getbitmap method just only get bitmap in memory
`private Bitmap bufferBitmap 
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
  return bufferBitmap;
 }`

Comment: Check if getBitmap() takes too much time. Is your surfaceview hardware accelerated?

Comment: gitBitmap() is determined not to spend time, surfaceView is in activity hardware accelerated. If I want to have a good performance, Should not be used canvas , shold used opengl to drawbitmap ?